# When to use React with npm?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

If we can use React without npm, why are there people still using it with npm? What is the relevance of npm? Do we need npm if our website is not just React-based, but also based on other languages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Npm is a package manager, its not just something that makes `react` work, but it also provides a way to manage versions, to manage dependencies, scripts and other things that otherwise would be a lot of manual work to be adding.
That said you can surely go without `npm`, `babel`, `webpack` and others. But given the simplicity to work with these, you lose more than what you gain, and if you set a package using the `create-react-app` command then you actually just have them in thre background and the setup is the quickest it can be for a "basic" project literally seconds and you have everything working with basic watch build and compiling functionalities.

If your website is served as a static bundle you can use anything but npm just makes your scripting easier, so you don't need to make `.sh` or `bat` scripts depending if you are on Linux or Windows (bash and powershel) . And you can also use npm packages that handle operating system changes for you already. Like `cross-env`, `jest` and others, that just work out of the box in any operating system, when installed as dependency via `npm`.

Comment: What is meant by 'website is served as a static bundle'? Why do static bundles not need npm? What are these .bash and bat scripts we are talking about here? Thanks much

Comment: When you build a website you can either make a bundle of files and serve it as static files, that never change unless you rebuild, or you can also build on request with server side rendering. When you serve as a bundle of statics you usually need to build the website somehow (mandatory if you are using react) as the browsers don't understand frameworks directly

Comment: Bash and bat scrips are meant to be used to organise the build and serving or starting of the servers and npm scripts could be just another way to execute scripts without to put them in a sh or bat file

Comment: meaning, if i will use React-CDN I will need to write these scripts myself which npm would have done for me otherwise? Can you give me the example scripts? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what you mean by your question, maybe if you post a question in SO it might be answered. To be honest, I don't know what you are asking.